# How one may enter to machine learning from point of view of Fourier analysis?

Tags: fourier-transform, machine-learning

I am a Ph.D. in Pure mathematics and my interest is operator theory and Fourier analysis. I am looking forward to any link, textbook or Ph.D. thesis which enters me to the context the "machine learning".

Comment: Maybe this is something you can look at? https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00368 Or is it just to learn more on the theory of machine learning? Because then I suggest 'Elements of statistical Learning' or 'Deep Learning' by Goodfellow et al.

Comment: You should read The Hundred Page Machine Learning Book this weekend. Then read An Introduction to Statistical Learning by Witten et al. Then read Deep Learning with Python by Chollet, the creator of Keras. Those three are quick and easy and have a big payoff. Then you have a choice of what to read next, but The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie et al is very popular.

Comment: @littleO Thanks a lot for your pay attention.